# Need a formula to know how many times 2 different numbers fit into a 3rd number.

Tags: real-numbers, word-problem, discrete-optimization

I am creating a chairs seating diagram and need a fast way to be able to input my 2 chair widths of 20", and 22" into a total width and for it to tell me the maximum amount of chairs that will fit in that row. I also need the output to be a whole number for both sizes.

For example I have a length of 160". In this example, I can actually get the most amount of chairs by using only (8) 20" chairs. It equaling a perfect width of 160" with no remaining.

However if I have a number of 144". Then the best config is (2) 22" chairs, and (5) 20" chairs.

The formula can have left over numbers such as the width being 145". Then the best config is the same as 144" (2) 22" chairs and (5) 20" chairs. I am not concerned with that remaining 1" left over from 145" since that total is 144" the extra 1" is of no concern.

Comment: This is not clear.  Isn't the answer obviously "use as many narrow chairs as you can."?   How could it ever help to use a wider chair?  For your second example, $144$, you use $7$ chairs of mixed type, but your could have just used $7$ narrow chairs.

Comment: You are correct, but since we do not have an infinite amount of 20" chairs a mixed amount must be used where possible. Also mathematically some cases may call for rows of all 22" chairs

Comment: If your metric is more complicated, you need to explain it.  In principle you could try to optimize several things but we need to know how you propose to weight the various goals.  We can't guess at those constraints.

Comment: @lulu - I guessed at the constraints. :-) And I think I got them right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples you gave, I'm assuming, even though you didn't state it, that you want to use up as much of the space as possible. Otherwise, just use only 20" chairs. Or maybe it's "I'd prefer 22" chairs, but not if it means having fewer chairs". Either way, here's an easy algorithm:

First, figure out how many 20" chairs you could fit.

Then, figure out how much space is left over.

For each 2" in the left over space, replace a 20" chair with a 22" chair.

Comment: Ah this is a great thought. Since we have limited quantities of both sizes a mixed row has to be used. Otherwise yes it makes the most sense to use all 20" chairs. Thank you

Comment: If this is the best answer, and answers your question, you should click the check mark on the left hand column to indicate so. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the knapsack problem.  Because you care only about the total number of chairs, you can ignore the larger chair and just use the floor function.

- For your first example, the maximum is $\lfloor 160 / \min(20,22) \rfloor = 8$.
- For your second example, the maximum is $\lfloor 144 / \min(20,22) \rfloor = 7$.
- For your third example, the maximum is $\lfloor 145 / \min(20,22) \rfloor = 7$.

Comment: Ah that is very useful, Thank you. However is there a simple way to know the specific number of chairs of each size that would be needed? Since in my use case I do need to know how many of each chair is need in the row. Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: Use none of the larger chairs. The number I reported is the number of smaller chairs.